# How to call thousands of AJAX nested GET requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to do thousands of AJAX GET Request - they need to be nested due to their dependency (which means: the next AJAX request uses variables from the response of the previous one).

I managed to request as many times as I could with the example below, but this is a case where I need to do it thousands of time, so impossible to write them like this.

I tried to write loops in many ways, but they all resulted in a non-expected behavior.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'urllink.com',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        }, success: function(responseJSON){

            var jsonResponse = Object.values(responseJSON).pop()
            alert(jsonResponse);


$.ajax({
        url: 'urllink.com'+jsonResponse,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        }, success: function(responseJSON){

            var jsonResponse = Object.values(responseJSON).pop()
            alert(jsonResponse);

           

        }


})
        }


})
```

Comment: Sounds like you would want to put your ajax call into a function and call it recursively.

Comment: Are you trying to DDOS the server? 

Comment: If possible, Id really look at creating a backend script to do the recursive work and send as few ajax requests as possible to that script, let it compile the results and send them back.

Comment: @SakoBu no, just finishing a coding exercise   (not a developer btw)

Comment: Use the callback to “recursively” call a function again when the XHR process is complete, make sure to handle error results and add some termination condition. Consider that the function is define as: function makeCall(..) {..}, then inside the function $.ajax is used and the success/error callbacks sullied call makeCall *again* (functions can use their own names inside their bodies). The top-level code can itself kickoff N makeCall’s, which roughly equate to N parallel streams of requests (limited by other factors).

Comment: If you want to write loops, you will need to use `async`/`await`. Without that, you'll have to resort to a recursive approach.

Comment: Some  of the solutions are not really making sense. What determines the number of requests? One request to the first url and then a request for each of the values it returns? What do you need to do with all the results?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm just defining a random number. The response of the previous request in fact the "/path" for the next one - and there I go. Until I finally get to the end of it - hopefully.

Comment: So you are not wanting to iterate over the returned `Object.values` array and make a request for each one? Still a bit unclear what purpose is here and what you need to do with all the response data

Comment: @charlietfl no, because the first get request only brings the value for the next one. Apparently, there isn't a way to access it all.

Trying to make an analogy: it's like navigating into folders. You open a folder, there's another folder, and then another folder. So, I need to do the request, to get the next request "/path" info. 

The purpose: It's a coding exercise, not sure if there's any practical application.

Comment: Ok so first request is the root folders... then you need to loop through all those making requests for each folder to return it's contents. Then loop through each of those until there is and end. None of the solutions shown are set up for this. In addition it;s not clear how you determine the end or what sample data looks like. I'm assuming also that you want to build a data tree similar to the folder structure but that's not clear either

Comment: Seeing some sample data would be really helpful here

Comment: @charlietfl

`{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ ( fn )
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )
pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ ( obj )
readyState: 4
responseJSON: {next: "/bucecarlus"}
responseText: "{"next":"/bucecarlus"}↵"
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value ) .... `

**responseJSON: {next: "/bucecarlus"}** it's what I use for the next request.

Comment: Retrieving it's being straight-foward and even getting the next request inside the new success - this is working. The problem is looping many times inside each success function.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let count = 0;
function req(url, amount) {
    let recall = this.req;
    $.ajax({
        url: `${url}`,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        },
        success: function (responseJSON) {
            var jsonResponse = Object.values(responseJSON).pop()
            alert(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
            count++
            if (amount > count) {
                recall(url, amount);
            }
        }
    });
};

req('urllink.com', 2);
```

What I did was making a `recall` variable that runs itself with the same parameters, and then just check for the `count` to execute itself.

Comment: Instead of incrementing a global `count`, you should just decrement the local `amount`

Comment: Inside the named function “req”, “req” is a bound variable that refers to the function. No need for the recall variable or “this.req” (which is really “window.req” in context).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function to make `ajax` calls and another function to call first function in a loop and then you pass the result parameter in each iteration

```
 function calls(val){
  var   res=$.ajax({
    url: 'urllink.com'+val,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    }, success: function(responseJSON){
  
        return Object.values(responseJSON).pop()
    }
 }).responseText
 return res
}
var val="intialvalue"
async function makecalls(){
  for (let i=0;i<1000;i++){
    var param= await calls(val)
           val=param
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `async`/`await`, you should not pass a `success` callback at all. Also there's not really a reason to put it into a separate function, it would work inline as well.

Comment: Right, return in `success` is useless and is not caught anywhere or passed to promise chain

Comment: @Begi I am passing the value from the previous call to the next call because the next call relies on the first call that's why but anyway I noticed that all what you appear to do is downvote me without good cause

Answer (score 0):

Consider a scaffold like the following. Each asynchronous request will run *concurrently* and spawn it’s own replacement when done. Details are left as an exercise.

```
let i = 1000;

function doRequest() {
    // some state advancement and termination condition
    // this can include the “target url” which can be supplied
    // as a parameter (eg. function doRequest(url)): adjust accordingly.
    if (i <= 0)
        return;
    i = i - 1;
    let x = i;
    console.log(x + “ starting”);

    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: function () {
             // don’t use alert here! >_<
             console.log(x + “ done”);
             // function has access to it’s own name
             // (this is a form of “stack less” recursion)
             // start the next asynchronous call!
             // tip: pass some “next url” result data for this problem
             doRequest();
        }
        // also handle failure case
    );
}
```

The *concurrent* self-replacing requests can be started N *parallel* times for independent subproblems. Browsers have a limit of a few *parallel* requests at a time (eg. 2..8 are common, well short of hundreds). The remote server may have even lower parallel capabilities.

```
// example only, call once with “start url” for this task
// as the specific problem establishes a data dependency
// and the requests cannot be run in parallel
// unless there is a method to divide the problem
for (let n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
    doRequest();
}
```

Free typos, iPhone makes this hard :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all requests are in order that they all provide a `next` property  in response object until the very last one not having that property (or it's value returns falsy) you should be able to use the following recursive promise chain.

End result will be an array of all the `next` values returned

```
const  getData = (path, results=[]) => {
   let url = 'urllink.com' + (path || '');
   // return an ajax promise 
   return $.getJSON(url).then(({next}) => {
       if(next){
         // store current value in results array
         results.push(next);
         // return another request promise
         return getData(next, results); 
       } else {
         // when run out of nexts return the array of data to the final then()
         return results;
       }
   });
}
```

Usage:

```
getData().then(data => console.log(data))// array of all the `next` values received
         .catch(err => console.log('Ooops, one of the requests failed'));
```